# How to enable Visual Basic support for XNA game studio?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, xna, visual-studio-express

I did read that with the latest version of XNA Game Studio Visual Basic support was added. I downloaded XNA Game Studio 4.0 Refresh and installed it. Source: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27599. But it only added the XNA Visual Studio templates to Visual C# 2010 Express and not to Visual Basic 2010 Express. Both IDEs are up to date (SP1). How can I enable XNA support for Visual Basic also?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Last I checked, XNA is only for C#... or at least only C# is officially supported/recommended. If you want VB.Net, you'll have to link the Assemblies yourself.

Comment: There's quite a few links on the net for XNA VB.NET - here's an older one:  http://www.alanphipps.com/VisualBasicdotNET-XNA-InstallXNA.html

Comment: They have added Visual Basic support with the latest version of XNA. You can read about it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb417503.aspx#ID4ESC. But perhaps Visual Basic 2010 Express is not supported, but I cannot find more information about it.

Comment: It seems that you have to install the Windows Phone 7.1 SDK which contains Visual Studio 2010 Express for Windows Phone. All the templates for developing XNA games using Visual Basic are located there.